# Html - single page - staying logged in

Tags: html, authentication

I have an Html page with a load of javascript that changes between views.

Some views require the person to be logged in, and consequently prompt for it.

How can I note the person has successfully logged in, using the javascript, that will not be a security issue, but will mean the person does not have to repeatedly log in for each view. I do not want to keep on going back to the server each time.

Edit:::

To explain more. Here are the problems I see.

Lets say I have the following in my javascript:

```
var isLoggedIn = true;
var userEmail = "myemail@mysite.com";
```

Anyone can hack my code to change these values and then get another person's info. That is not good. So instead of isLoggedIn do I need something like a hashed password stored in the javascript:

```
var userHashedPassword = "shfasjfhajshfalshfla";
```

But every where I read, they say you should not keep any password stuff in memory for any length of time.

So what variables do I keep and where? The user will be constantly flicking between non-user specific divs and  user-based divs, and I do not want them to have to constantly log in each time.

****Edit 2:*****

This is what I am presently doing, but am not happy with.

There is a page/div with 3 radio buttons. Vacant games (does not require user information), My Game (requires knowledge of user and must be signed in), My Old Games (also requires logged in status).

When first going on the page it defaults on vacant games, and gets the info from the server, which does not require login.

In two variables in the javascript I have

```
var g_Email = "";
var g_PasswordEncrypted = "";
```

Note these are both 0 length strings.

If the user wants to view their games, they click the My Games radio button. The code checks to see if the g_Email and PasswordEncrypted are 0 length strings, if they are it goes to a div where they need to login.

When the user submits their loging info, it goes to the server, checks their details, and sends back an ok message, and all the info (My Games) that the user was requesting.

So if the login was a success, then

```
g_Email = "myemail@mysite.com";
g_PasswordEncrypted = "this is and encrypted version of the password";
```

If there is any failure in login, these two are instead set to "".

Then when the user navigates to any page that requires login, it checks to see if these two strings are filled. If they are, it will ***not*** go to a login page when you request information like My Games.

Instead it just sends the info in these strings to the server, along with the My Games request. The server still checks these Email and encrypted password are valid before sending back the info, but at the client side, the user has not had to repeatedly input this info each time.

If there is any failure in the server request, it just sends back an error message (I am using ajax) in the callback function, which knows to set the g_Email and g_PasswordEncrypted to "" if there is anything wrong. (In the latter case, the client side knows it has to re-request the login details because these two strings are "").

The thing I do not like is I am keeping the Encryted password on the person's client machine. If they walk away from their machine, someone can open up the debugger in something like chrome and extract these details, and then hack it into their machine some time later.

Comment: Set isLoggedIn=true and the userEmail only after a user succesfully logged in to the server, they shouldn't be hardcoded in the javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If javascript loads content for each view from the server then it is for server to know if a current session belongs to logged user or not. In case the user is not logged, the server responses with prompt to login, otherwise it sends content of the view.

If javascript bulds content for the views deriving it from the data that was already received from the server then it should use some variable keeping state of the user (logged/not_logged). And depending on that value javascript will either show a prompt to login or display required content of the view.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head, but I am still unsure what to do. I have made edits to explain more.

Comment: It is not clear what scheme you use. Do "logged contents" and "not logged contents"  always exist on the page and you just decide in javascript which content to display on a view depending on the user state? How do you know if a user is logged or not? Do you use ajax for login to server or HTML form?

Comment: Good question. I have explained more in ***Edit 2***.

Comment: Khmmm... What backend you use as a server? Why don't just keep logged sessions on server so that client doesn't re-authenticate itself on each view?

Comment: At the moment I am using just php. However, long term I would like to use NodeJs, so everything can be written in javascript. But please assume php for now. How would I keep this logged in? I am not great at php, I just use it to do database lookup, nothing more. Also, how would the client machine know the client has been logged in at the back end - just have a flag on the client machine saying all is well?

Comment: Have a look at PHP sessions. You can google for PHP scripts handling user logins and logged sessions.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, due to the $_SESSION comment above by Evgeny S.